# How to handle scrolling with Collapsing Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, material-design

I added collapsing toolbar in my app but now it only collapses when a user scrolls the image view inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout. How can collapse the toolbar when a user scrolls from anywhere within the view?

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.ProfileActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/profile_contents"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

These are the contents of profile_contents.xml for now because I am going to add more items in future.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_displayName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="loading name..."
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="loading status..."
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_displayName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/profile_send_req_btn"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_button_bg"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/send_friend_request"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_status" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you put the profile_contents.xml source code ?

Comment: i just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your included layout inside `NestedScrollView` view, since the `ConstraintLayout`  is not a scrollable view.

Like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/profile_contents"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Don't forget to put the `app:layout_behavior` in the `NestedScrollView`

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `profile_contents` layout's root view

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

> We need to define an association between the AppBarLayout and the View that will be scrolled. Add an `app:layout_behavior` to a RecyclerView or any other View capable of nested scrolling such as NestedScrollView. The support library contains a special string resource `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` that maps to `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`, which is used to notify the `AppBarLayout` when scroll events occur on this particular view. The behavior must be established on the view that triggers the event.

The above text is from here https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Comment: when i add this line my included layout jumps outside the layout and doesn't still scroll

Comment: Try adding it in the root view of the profile_contents layout